# What statistical test would you recommend to compare two animal behavior sampling methods?

Tags: lab-techniques, statistics, biostatistics

I am doing a lab where I am comparing the scanning method and focal animal method. Each method will give me the following:

- Scanning method: occurrence frequency for each behavior (%),
- focal animal method:the occurrence frequencies (%), as well as the duration for each behavior.

I was thinking a chi-squared test or a t-test somehow but I'm not sure which to do or how to format them. Should I somehow compare the occurrence frequencies?

Not sure if this info is useful, but I normally use R for my statistical test but have never used my own data, only example data. I was going to record my data in excel and import it into R. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to compare between the methods? If you want to decide which is the correct method to measure, statistics isn't the answer. You need to consider the accuracy you obtain with each method, the objective, the data achieved, the resolution and your sample size. among other paremters

Comment: I agree with @Hachiloni that you seem to compare apples and oranges. The two methods provide you with different information, i.e., you measure different things. Perhaps, you could give more background about what you are doing, which could help to understand your problem better.

Comment: Also agree with Hachiloni. I think that we need more details about your experimental setup or study system. The question is not how to analyze the data but which addresses your study question. For example, I might ask why you don't take a video of the whole population and then do a focal analysis on each individual at every time point. Likely there is some technical difficulty with this, but it's really hard for us to tell!